# Using gettext in configure

Tags: osx, compiling, homebrew

I'm trying to compile a program which requires gettext (for intltools) on macOS. I tried the following commands to run the configure script:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include ./configure
LDFLAGS=/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib CPPFLAGS=/usr/local/opt/gettext/include ./configure
```

In the first case it failed with the following error message

```
configure: error: GNU gettext tools not found; required for intltool
```

In the latter case it couldn't find the C compiler

What's the right way to solve this kind of problem?
I understand that this is probably related to [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/13921)

Comment: This should probably go to Ask Different, to Unix & Linux, or to Android enthusiasts. Or is it a meta-joke with the term homebrewing being used in the custom rom community?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with brewing.

Comment: I am going to close and/or move this to a more relevant SE site.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong group choice to post the question.

Comment: Does the homebrew `gettext` package install the "gettext tools"? Are these available in your `$PATH`? The gettext tools includes `xgettext`, `msgfmt` and others.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes the packages are installed, they are just not linked on macOS as described [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/13921), so I was looking for a way to solve the problem properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `configure` script fails because it can't find the `gettext` tools in the current `$PATH`.  These tools include `xgettext`, `msgfmt` and other binaries.

On macOS with Homebrew, the `gettext` Homebrew package does actually install these binaries, but they are located in the `/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1/bin` directory rather than directly in `/usr/local/bin`.

The reason for this is that [Homebrew installs all "keggs" in the "cellar"](http://rkulla.blogspot.se/2014/03/the-path-to-homebrew.html), and `gettext` is a "keg" package.

If everything is working as intended, your `gettext` tools should already be symbolically linked from the `Cellar` directory to `/usr/local/bin`, and if your Homebrew setup is correct, `/usr/local/bin` should be in your `$PATH`.

Obviously, this is *not* set up properly, so I'd suggest making sure that your `$PATH` is correctly set up with `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` and that the links for the `gettext` tools exists from the cellar to the `/usr/local/bin` directory.  Fixing one or both of those things will resolve this issue for you.

---

Update:  According to [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/747619/452045), symbolic links to the `gettext` tools may not be set up properly by default.  The following command will fix it:

```
$ brew link gettext --force
```

Once you have compiled your other application, you may undo the above with

```
$ brew unlink gettext
```

... if you wish.

[This other answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016758/4941495) goes on to explain that executables of Homebrew packages that are "keg-only" (`gettext` is one of those) are *not* linked from the "cellar" to `/usr/local/bin`.  This is by design. This explains why the `brew link` step will be necessary to get your `configure` script working properly.

The reason "keg-only" binaries are not put in you `$PATH` by default is that they may interfere with similarly named tools already present in the macOS base system.